# Compatibility of nskeyedarchiver between OS X and iOS

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, nscoding

If I share a class implementing the NSCoding protocol between a desktop cocoa application and an iOS application, will I also be able to share a datafile created by archiving an object between those two applications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files archived with NSKeyedArchiver are compatible between both plattforms. You just have to look out for classes that are not available on both plattforms like:

- NSColor / UIColor
- NSImage / UIImage
- …

Since those are not available on both plattforms you will not be able to unarchive them on the other plattform.